# Filtering DataGridView rows when DataSource is bound to a EF5 Entity collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, databound

I have a DataGridView which is databound to a BindingList

```
private void InitGrid()
{
    Ctx.MyEntitySet.Load();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Ctx.MyEntitySet.Local.ToBindingList();
    dataGridView1.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["UnwantedCol1"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["UnwantedCol2"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["UnwantedCol3"].Visible = false;
}
```

and a filtering TextBox, with a TextChanged event handled like this

```
private void textBoxFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string filter = textBoxFilter.Text.Trim();
        ((DataView)dataGridView1.DataSource).RowFilter = filter;
        textBoxFilter.BackColor = SystemColors.AppWorkspace;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        textBoxFilter.BackColor = Color.Red;
        ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
        tip.SetToolTip(textBoxFilter, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I run the code, the data is displayed correctly, but when I try to type something like `ColumnName like '%sometext%'` in my filter textbox, I get an exception saying I can't cast a 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.ObservableBackedBindingList`1[MyEntity]' to 'System.Data.DataView'.

Can anyone give me a pointer?

Thanks,
F.

**RESOLVED:**

Added a generic extension method

```
public static class LocalExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, bool> filterParam)
    {
        return list.Where(filterParam);
    }
}
```

And modified TextChanged event handler like this:

```
private void textBoxFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string filter = textBoxFilter.Text.Trim();

        dataGridView1.DataSource =
            Ctx.MyEntitySet.Local
            .Filter(x =>
                x.EntityPropertyToSearchIn1.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper()) ||
                x.EntityPropertyToSearchIn2.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper())
            ).ToList();

        textBoxFilter.BackColor = SystemColors.AppWorkspace;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        textBoxFilter.BackColor = Color.Red;
        ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
        tip.SetToolTip(textBoxFilter, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: At first, I can tell you the types are incompatible. You are binding a BindingList to be used as a DataView (the type of the DataGridView), which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you cannot put the [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696575%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) directly into your DataGridView. You'll need to define a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) and assign the BindingList to this BindingSource. Try this to see if it works:

```
Ctx.MyEntitySet.Load();
BindingSource yourBS = new BindingSource();
yourBS.DataSource = Ctx.MyEntitySet.Local.ToBindingList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = yourBS;
dataGridView1.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
dataGridView1.Columns["UnwantedCol1"].Visible = false;
dataGridView1.Columns["UnwantedCol2"].Visible = false;
dataGridView1.Columns["UnwantedCol3"].Visible = false;
```

I hope it works. :)

Regards.

Comment: The binding was already working. The data filtering is the one that is not working. If I apply your edit, I get the same exception in the TextChanged eventhandler (with BindingSource instead of BindingList)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a new BindingList that is filtered. Easy to do with LINQ. See [Filtering a Binding List](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/cb7e21ec-4ac9-45ec-824a-e527d194c97c/filtering-a-binding-list)

```
try
{
    string filter = textBoxFilter.Text.Trim();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<YOUR_ENTITY>(Ctx.MyEntitySet.Local.ToBindingList().Where(x => x.EntityPropertyToSearchIn1.ToUpper().Contains(filter)).ToList<YOUR_ENTITY>());
    textBoxFilter.BackColor = SystemColors.AppWorkspace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is the VB equivalent for the extension method:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module LocalExtensions

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function Filter(Of T)(list As IEnumerable(Of T), filterParam As Func(Of T, Boolean)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Return list.Where(filterParam)
    End Function

End Module
```